# How to create SAML assertion signature in node.js

Tags: node.js, hash, saml, digital-signature, x509certificate

I am working with an external api that requires me to create a saml assertion for mutual tls authentication. The client I am building to communicate with the api is written in nodejs. I was unable to find any libraries that would handle creating saml assertions for me so I ended up templating a saml assertion imported from an xml file and populated the necessary fields using handlebars. The only thing I am missing now is the signature, which I am having a hard time finding documentation on generating.

Here is an example of what I am trying to complete:

```
<ds:Signature>
    <ds:SignedInfo>
        <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
        <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
        <ds:Reference URI="#_df0cbca2-3511-4586-b5f3-0211b1700413">
            <ds:Transforms>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            </ds:Transforms>
            <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
            <ds:DigestValue>{{fillMeIn}}</ds:DigestValue>
        </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>{{MeToo!}}</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
        <ds:X509Data>
            <ds:X509Certificate>...secret...certificate...</ds:X509Certificate>
        </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
</ds:Signature>
```

In the previous example I need values for the signature and digest, Any insight into how to generate these values would be appreciated. The ability to generate them dynamically (programatically) would be ideal. We are using self signed X509 certificates. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found the [xml-crypto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-crypto) library, which seems like it does what I am looking for.

Comment: I tried this, but could not get it to work (https://github.com/node-saml/xml-crypto/issues/393). How did you do it?

Comment: Have you tried referring to the root element (XPath: `/*`) instead of the document (XPath: `/`)? It would evaluate to [node type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) `1` (having `attributes`) instead of `9`.

Comment: @ajthinking - I cannot reproduce the problem when using my own certificate and private key, the signature is generated successfully, see online here: https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/RustyRoastedAbstractions#index.js. Possibly a problem with your certificate and/or private key. Post non-productive sample data.

Comment: Fixed Xpath! @Topaca, I could get it to compute with a fresh dummy cert so you must be right it is about my cert which unfortunately I cant share. It is supposed to be x.509 cert, looks just liked the dummy one I created with openssl. Tried setting 'signatureAlgorithm' to sha1 or sha256, just getting ERR_OSSL_UNSUPPORTED